# Is 'dweller' BE or AE? How can I know words are BE or AE?

Tags: word-usage

Is 'dweller' Britsh English or American English, or both?

I rarely see this word, maybe it is American English, or maybe I didn't read enough...things.

How can I know whether words are Britsh English or American English?

Is there a way to look it up?

Thank you!

Comment: What a shame, user xxxxxx had posted a really good answer. I don't know why he deleted it. Only users with 10k (or is it 20K?)  can see the 'deleted' post.

Comment: Don't take it at face value, but I believe searching the respective corpora and observing the frequencies might hint at the form of English in which it's most common. For instance, [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams) you may choose "American English" and "British English" from the drop-down list and compare the percentages assigned to the queried term in a specific time period.

Comment: Just look the word up in a good dictionary such as [Oxford](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/dweller). If  word is used only or mostly in one dialect, it will tell you.

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way? Is there anything more I could have explained?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Thank you so much! I somehow missed your update and just saw it now. It helps greatly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The noun **dweller** is known in many dialects of English. It is not exclusive to British or American English.

> - There are two obvious rich types in China-the provincials and the **city dwellers**
> - *Where possible, **slum dwellers** are allowed to buy the land they are "squatting" on*.

How to tell if a word is a feature of one particular dialect?

This is fairly easy for native speakers; if they don't recognise an English word in their dialect, they might guess it is one of the following: British English; American English; Australian English; or Indian English. These are the most common English dialects, but there are many others.

> How can I know whether words are British English or American English?

For learners of English, the best way of knowing is to look the word up in any good dictionary. If a word, or idiom is common or confined to one dialect, a competent dictionary will usually mention it.

Lets take the expression *apartment dwellers* as an example

> - *‘For most New York City **apartment dwellers**, though, the answer lies somewhere in between.’*
> - Sure, homeowners with children pay less than childless **apartment dwellers** at the same income level

Safe to say, when you see the word *apartment*, in the vast majority of cases, the writer is American English.

Under **apartment**, [Macmillan Dictionary](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/apartment) says

> 1. a set of rooms for living in, usually on one floor of a large building.
>      **The usual British word is** ***flat***.
> 2. AMERICAN an apartment building

The expression *flat dweller* is far less common than *apartment dweller*, but I found a few instances on the net.

> - Those without their own drive and **flat-dwellers** in particular, have always found it difficult to use an electric car because of a need to trail wires across pavements.
> - The constituency is split between conservative, long-established residents who tend to back the LDP and newer **flat-dwellers** who live near an office district and are fed up with the ruling party.

and [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=apartment%20dwellers%2Cflat%20dwellers&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Capartment%20dwellers%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cflat%20dwellers%3B%2Cc0) seems to confirm the trend.

The term *resident* is instead more commonly used in conjunction with *flats* and *block of flats*

> - The new flats will offer its **residents** iconic views over the River Thames
> - Not the most suitable pet for **residents** of blocks of flats, then.

Answer (score -2):

It's not a commonly word in American English, but it's fine if used correctly.  You can say an animal is a "bottom (of the ocean, or a lake/river) dweller" or a person or animal is a "cave dweller".  So as far as I can tell the answer is it's neither BE or AE.